# How to force user to select a value from dropdown and button to enable the save button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I would like to know how to add a listener for the combo box from the form? I already have a code for the listener for the radio button. What I want is to force the user to select from the combo box and radio button before the submit button is enabled.

The script below is for when the radio button is selected the submit button is enabled.

```
    EnableSubmit = function (val) {
        var sbmt = document.getElementById("Submit");

        if (val.checked == true) {
            sbmt.disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            sbmt.disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

[Here is my jsfiddle so far.](https://jsfiddle.net/2d61fzex/)

The question is how can I add a listener for the combo box to enable the submit button once all the fields in the form is filled up. Thank you very much in advance!

**UPDATE**

I added a `val.selected!=""` to the script. It kind of work first try but when you change your answer the submit button gets disabled and enabled. I guess it shouldn't be `onclick` but I dunno for sure. Any ideas?

[Here is the jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/2d61fzex/1/)

**UPDATE 2**
It seems only the radio button enables the submit button. T^T

Comment: i make a `jquery` sample, if you want native javascript just tell, and i will convert.

Comment: jquery or javascript is fine for me but your answer below doesn't work when I use it on my site. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, if this code are work for you.

```js
$('.rad,#1,#2,#3').on('change', function() {
var sub = $('#Submit');
var rad = $('.rad').is(":checked");
var sel1 = $('#1');
var sel2 = $('#2');
var sel3 = $('#3');
  if (sel1.val() && sel2.val() && sel3.val() && rad) {
    sub.prop("disabled", false);
  }else{
   sub.prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  test 1&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <select id="1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <br> test 2&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <select id="2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <br> test3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <select id="3">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <br> test4&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" id="radio" name="radio" value="1" class="rad">1
  <input type="radio" id="radio" name="radio" value="2" class="rad">2
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```

Comment: One case that is not considered in your current code: if `Submit` is enabled and I select the empty option in a `select` element, the button is not disabled.

Comment: Well it seems to work on jsfiddle but using it in my site it doesn't work. I don't know why. x.x

Comment: well there is no error. the submit button doesn't get enabled even if I filled up my form..

Comment: but your project are online? check the jquery if properly connected, or maybe you dont have jquery because your first project are native javascript.

Comment: I already added the script for jquery in my project still no good. x.x Thank you for your answer btw! It is really good but I guess its not compatible with my project.

Comment: @mmativ hiii~ I finally got your code to work~ Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 3):

Because I tend to be the most lazy person ever (read: someone who likes being effecient) I tend to use html5's [form.checkValidity](http://caniuse.com/#search=checkValidity) function, which appears usable in most modern browsers. If you plan to allow less than IE11, Edge 13, Firefox 46, or Chrome 50 (not including the mobile browsers) then this is definitely not the method for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#register input,textarea,select').on('change', function() {
    var form = this.form;
    var isValid = form.checkValidity();
    $(':submit').attr('disabled', !isValid);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="register">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Hello" required />Click the Radio Button
  <input type="radio" name="something" value="yes" required/>
  <br />
  <select name="something_else" required>
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">TWo</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" disabled="true">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is the best because it's the simplest. Why reinvent the wheel in jquery when every modern browser already does it for you and does it better. +1

Comment: Does this works on mobile browsers? Like Safari for iphone and other mobile browsers?

Comment: nice code, you just check the form if valid, thanks for share.

Comment: @user3771102 I honestly cannot say. Reading through the CanIUse website it says `.checkValidity()` has some issues in iOS Safari, Safari and Opera Mini. I can't say how much it will impact your code, but I can say I tend to do much more thorough checks for data server-side since someone could just inspect the element and set the disabled attribute to false if they *really* wanted to submit false data.

Comment: Oh that's a bit risky. Most of the people here are using iphone so most probably they are using safari for their browser. I'll check if this will work out. Thank you very much!

Comment: just remember that javascript validation should ***not*** be your final verification step! otherwise, perhaps using the [jQuery Validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) might work best for you?

Comment: Well so far your code works well. I'll let the QA check if there will be no problem with this code. If none then its all good. :D Thank you again. I'll keep the plugin in mind. :)

Comment: Good to hear. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

So, I created a generic validation for you:

```
$(".input-required").change(function() {
  var allRequiredValid = true;
  $(".input-required").each(function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    if (($input.prop("type") === "radio" && $("[name='" + $input.prop("name") + "']:checked").length == 0) || $(this).val() == "") {
      allRequiredValid = false;
    }
  });
  if (allRequiredValid) {
    $("#Submit").removeProp("disabled");
  }
});
```

you just need to add the class `input-required` on the input you would like to validate:

```
<form>
  test 1&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <select id="1" class="input-required">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <br> test 2&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <select id="2" class="input-required">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <br> test3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <select id="3" class="input-required">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <br> test4&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" id="radio" name="radio" value="1"  class="input-required">1
  <input type="radio" id="radio" name="radio" value="2"  class="input-required"> 2
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```

PS: I didn't validate checkboxes

here is your updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/diegopolido/2d61fzex/3/

Comment: Hi! I can't use your code since I have a specific class on my fields. But thank you for your answer. I might use it in my other projects. :)

Comment: couldn't you add another class? haha

Comment: well I could but I wasn't the one who code it and I don't want to change it because it looks weird. not the usual `class="name"`. It actually looks like this: `class="<%=option.class%>"><%=option.name%` so I'm not sure whether I can add another class.

Comment: class="input-required <%=option.class%>"><%=option.name%>" ;)

Comment: PS: it's using jquery ;)

Comment: Its weird when I select the any of the fields the submit button gets enabled.

Comment: On my code. :D It seems that there is some conflict in my code. I dunno for sure.

Comment: did you remove the onclick on the radios and add the class on all the required fields?

Comment: yes I did. :) Still it gets enabled but when you submit it you get to the error page but when you filled it up you get to the correct page.